# Wordpress Thickbox Integrated but not Working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

My blog, [mberkompas.com](http://www.mberkompas.com), uses wordpress with a thickbox integration.  Although all the the thickbox files are loaded and the images have a thickbox class, they still load in a new tab.

When examining my JS console, I discovered that thickbox.js is encountering an error.

```
thickbox.js:26Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'live'
```

I'm still an amateur at jQuery and don't quite no what's going on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I am getting (checked with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) is inside this function (inside thickbox.js):

```
//add thickbox to href & area elements that have a class of .thickbox
function tb_init(domChunk){
 jQuery(domChunk).live('click', tb_click);
}
```

It says the `live()` method couldn't be found. You are using jQuery version 1.2.x and the [live() method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was added in version 1.3.x. So, upgrading jQuery to latest version, or at least a 1.3.x version, would fixed that bug.

Comment: You're right.  Wordpress loads the latest version by default but my theme then loaded 1.2.  Got rid of the call to 1.2 and there are no longer any errors, but thickbox still isn't working.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working right now.  Just didn't click on an image with the thickbox class.  Thanks!